# Ensure order of execution promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have two promises like the one below at my endpoint:

```
request.post({
          url: url,
          json: smsSTART,
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
      },function(error, response, body){

      });
```

I would like to ensure that "Request 1" is executed first than "Request 2"

Looking for I found the promise.race, but I saw some criticism about it.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Just call Request 2 in first promise resolve.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Promise.all` and call both calls at the same time and use response from array returned to .then

Comment: I don't see two requests in your code? And I don't see any *promises* at all.

Comment: Bergi I just put that piece of code to not get too big.

Rikin I tried to put request 2 in the first resolves, but in some cases the order was not followed. I'll try Promise.all and Matt's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The example function looks like an async callback rather than a promise. The [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) module wraps [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait) in a promise.

```
 const rp = require('request-promise')

 async function post(url, payload){
   return rp({
     method: 'POST',
     uri: url,
     json: true,
     body: payload,
   })
 }

 async function posts(){
   let post1 = await post('https://me.com/path1', { request: 1 })
   let post2 = await post('https://me.com/path2', { request: 2 })
 }

 posts()
```

`async`/`await` are available in Node.js v7.6+ and via Babel.

Comment: This is newer syntax. Not everyone is in a position to use the `async` keyword.

Comment: Node 7.6+ or Babel required. Feel free to add the translation but async is much easier and current LTS so I'm done with `.then`s =)